# Java, Import Class From File

Tags: java, windows, class, import

I'm writing a java program and wanted to make a class that can be called on to make a quick log to the cmd (I'm still in my testing phase, figuring stuff out). I have a file and a folder with another file in it.

- `LaunchProgram.java`
- `helping`

  - `Dbg.class`
  - `Dbg.java`

The summarized contents of `LaunchProgram.class` (the stuff that is relevant):

```
import helping.Dbg;

public class LaunchProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dbg("Testing");
    }
}
```

The contents of `Dbg.class`:

```
package helping;

public class Dbg{
    public static void main(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

When I do `javac Dbg.java` in cmd, it runs without any error, producing `Dbg.class`.

When I do `javac LaunchProgram.java` in cmd, I get the following error:

```
LaunchProgram.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                Dbg("Testing");
                ^
symbol:   method Dbg(String)
location: class LaunchProgram
```

I'm not sure what's happened to cause this, and I've looked everywhere about this but can't find a solution. Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is corrected code for what you were trying to do:

```
public class LaunchProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dbg.log("Testing");
    }
}

public class Dbg {
    public static void log(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

But Apache log4j is a much better way to do logging in your application.  Here is a skeleton code for your `LaunchProgram` class which uses log4j to log a message:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LaunchProgram {
    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LaunchProgram.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args){
        logger.info("Testing");
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need a separate class to log, but rather you can log directly from the class you need to record a message.

Comment: I'm going to look into this. Sadly I can't choose two answers, they're both very good... I'm going to try this out and see what happens.

Comment: This fixed the issue along with the other answer. This one fixed the overall issue, but I believe would have led to another error if I didn't also follow EJP's answer. Since this one dealt with the bulk of the issue, I'm marking it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. `Dbg` is a class, not a method, and as it's a helper class it won't have a `main()` method of its own. Rather it should hav something like a `log` method that does the logging and is called by the other class.
2. I suspect you're not compiling the code correctly. You need to do this, in the directory that contains both `LaunchProgram.java` and the directory `helping`:

   ```
   javac helping/Dbg.java
   javac LaunchProgram.java
   ```

   Actually you don't need the first line at all. The second line will compile both classes. Both commands will put the corresponding .class files into the right directories. Then to run it:

   ```
   java LaunchProgram
   ```

Basically you should always be in the directory that is at the head of the package structure.

Comment: So when I compiled Dbg.java, I should not have compiled it from the folder it is in, but instead from the folder LaunchProgram is in, and could have done it all by just compiling LaunchProgram... this helps alot. I will look at this and try it out.

Comment: This worked and thanks a bunch, but the other answer fixed an issue inside the actual code, without which I wouldn't have been able to compile even with this solution. You fixed the problem I would have had if I used his solution without it. I don't know if I'm able to +1, since I don't have enough reputation... But thanks. EDIT - I did +1, looks like it works now.